# APFS encrypted sparsebundle won't fully compact

Tags: sparsebundle, apfs

I have an APFS encrypted sparsebundle saved on my HD. It is not a time machine backup, rather something I created and maintain manually. On occasion I perform an `hdiutil compact` to reclaim HD space.

High Sierra (10.13.6) Finder reports that the sparsebundle bands take about 4.45 GB of storage, but when mounted, Disk Utility (among other things) reports that only about 2.21 GB is used inside the volume.

Compacts don't reclaim the difference for me. I have tried to `secureerase` the free space, to no avail. I can't find any obvious explanation using Disk Utility.

I am unfamiliar with APFS itself.

Am I missing something? Am I able to 'recover' my ~2 GB?